# How to access VSTS Variable Groups from YAML build pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm currently in the process of converting VSTS build pipelines to [YAML build definions](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/blob/master/docs/preview/yamlgettingstarted.md). However I can't yet find a way to use variables of a [Variable Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=vsts) within my YAML file. If I reference a variable, just like before within a build pipeline, the PowerShell script doesn't seem to be able to find it.

```
- powershell: |
    Write-Output Testing...
    Write-Output "DatabaseName: $(AzureSqlDb_DatabaseName)"
  displayName: Output Library Vars
```

The detailed error message is as follows:

```
AzureSqlDb_DatabaseName : The term 'AzureSqlDb_DatabaseName' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\a\_temp\e06f9ee7-8418-4339-a976-ed78a0e71021.ps1:3 char:31
+ Write-Output "DatabaseName: $(AzureSqlDb_DatabaseName)"
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (AzureSqlDb_DatabaseName:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

##[debug]Exit code: 1
##[debug]Leaving Invoke-VstsTool.
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

As you can see, I've already enabled system.debug for the build pipeline. So:

- Is it already supported to use variable groups?
- If yes, what is the way to reference those variables?

Comment: Instead of using $(AzureSqlDb_DatabaseName), it also doesn't work when using $env:AzureSqlDb_DatabaseName. Although, no error appears in that case.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52372291/azure-devops-vsts-link-variable-group-through-yaml?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3):

The solution was very simple. Just like with a normal build pipeline, you also need to link a variable group to the YAML build pipeline from the VSTS portal. The way to this is described here: [Use a variable group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=vsts#use-a-variable-group).

Comment: For those of you that get stuck on this, the "Variables" tab in Azure DevOps is hidden behind the "Edit" link of the "Pipelines > Builds" screen.